# Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'current_date' '(' ')' in expression specification

Tags: python, pyhive

I tried using pyhive to execute SQL statements:

`select current_date();`

But it made an error just like the title.

```
    raise OperationalError(response)
pyhive.exc.OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=40000, errorMessage=u"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'current_date' '(' ')' in expression specification", sqlState=u'42000', infoMessages=[u"*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'current_date' '(' ')' in expression specification:28:27", u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:335', u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:199'
```

I also tried to remove the parentheses, but it still couldn't work

```
    raise OperationalError(response)
pyhive.exc.OperationalError: TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=40000, errorMessage=u"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'current_date' ';' '<EOF>' in expression specification", sqlState=u'42000', infoMessages=[u"*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:19 cannot recognize input near 'current_date' ';
```

How should I solve this problem